# Timer on atmega328p

Tags: c, microcontroller

So we had a task in school that every 10ms a variable (millisekunden)
schould increase by 10. We were using the CTC Mode, i set the OCR0A to 157, the
prescaler was 1024. The variable (millisekunden) increases every 10ms for 10, and
when it reaches 1000 , we schould print it out, and repeat that every 1000.
I always get an error : avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
0x00 != 0x0c
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
Can anyone check out my code if it is even correct programmed? Im using atmega328p
it has 16MHz. So i calculated 1/ 16 MHz * 1024(prescaler) * OCRA(157) and we get 10milli
seconds.

---

```
#include "Arduino.h"

unsigned long int t_ref; 

volatile unsigned long int millisekunden; // milli seconds timer
unsigned long int last_msg;               
char buffer[64];
unsigned int c;

void setup() {
 
  // Timer 0 
  TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01);               // CTC Modus
  TCCR0B |= (1 << CS02) | (1 << CS00); // Prescaler 1024
  
  OCR0A = 155;

  // Compare Interrupt 
  TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (millisekunden - last_msg >= 1000) {
    sprintf(buffer, "t=[%lu] PINB=[%2.2x]", millisekunden,PINB);
    Serial.println(buffer);
    last_msg = millisekunden;
  }

}
 
// Timer-Interrupt-Routine
ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
  millisekunden = millisekunden + 10;
}
```

---

datasheet from µC : https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf

Comment: Are you actually getting interrupts? Using `ISR(x)` will tell the compiler to add extra/hidden prolog/epilog code so `x` will be able to function as an ISR but I think your setup code has to call a registration function to connect `x` as the ISR for a given interrupt type/number

Comment: yes im getting interrupts.